# UITableViewCell Subtitle not updating correctly from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays, uitableview

Im currently working on a simple workout tracker app where i have a table view and each workout plan data is loaded onto each cells.

Im using subtitle for the tableview cell style that i have selected in the storyboard.

I put each exercise names onto text label and the number of reps and sets onto the detailed label.

my problem is that the data for exercises load correctly to each row's text label with respect to the workout array, but the reps & sets info is not loaded correctly.

**Week1_3ViewController.m**

```
#import "Week1_3ViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface Week1_3ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *workouts;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *reps;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *days;

@end

@implementation Week1_3ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;

    self.workouts = @[@{@"name" : @"SQUATS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"BENT OVER ROWS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"BENCH PRESS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"OVERHEAD PRESS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"EXTERNAL ROTATIONS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"SEATED CALF RAISES", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"MOUNTAIN CLIMBERS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"PLANKS", @"days" : @"DAY 1"}, @{@"name" : @"DEADLIFT", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"KNEELING LANDMINE PRESS", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"ALT. ARNOLD PRESS", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"ALT. FRONT LUNGE", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"PULL OVER", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"WEIGHTED CRUNCHES", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"SIDE PLANKS", @"days" : @"DAY 2"}, @{@"name" : @"FRONT SQUAT", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"T-BAR ROW", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"DIPS", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"UPRIGHT ROW", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"GLUTE BRIDGES (WEIGHTED)", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"STANDING CALF RAISES", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}, @{@"name" : @"RUSSIAN TWIST", @"days" : @"DAY 3"}].mutableCopy;

    self.reps = @[@"15, 12, 10, 8, 6", @"12, 10, 8, 6, 6", @"15, 12, 10, 8, 6", @"12, 10, 8, 6, 6", @"3 x 12", @"3 x 15", @"3 x 30 SECONDS", @"3 x 30 SECONDS", @"15, 12, 10, 8, 6", @"15, 12, 10, 8, 8", @"12, 10, 8, 8, 6", @"5 x 10", @"3 x 15", @"3 x 15", @"3 x 30 SECONDS", @"15, 12, 10, 8, 6", @"12, 10, 8, 8, 6", @"5 x 15", @"15, 12, 10, 8, 8", @"3 x 10", @"3 x 15", @"3 x 30 (15 EACH SIDE)"];
    self.days = @[@"DAY 1", @"DAY 2", @"DAY 3"];


    self.title = @"WEEK 1-3, PHASE 1";

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - DataSource helper methods

- (NSArray *) itemsInDays:(NSString *)targetDays {
    NSPredicate *matchingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"days == %@", targetDays];
    NSArray *daysItems = [self.workouts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matchingPredicate];

    return daysItems;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInDays:(NSString *)targetDays {
    return [self itemsInDays:targetDays].count;
}

- (NSDictionary *)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *days = self.days[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *daysItems = [self itemsInDays:days];
    NSDictionary *item = daysItems[indexPath.row];

    return item;
}

- (NSInteger)itemIndexForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger index = [self.workouts indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:item];

    return index;
}

#pragma mark - table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return self.days.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self numberOfItemsInDays:self.days[section]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"workoutrow";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *workouts = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = workouts[@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_reps objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //    NSLog(@"cell.textLabel.text %@", cell.textLabel.text);


    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;

}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.days[section];
}





@end
```

and here is my app simulator running result.
[![simulator result][1]][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQWzO.png

you can see that the subtitle label "15, 12, 10, 8, 6" of "DEAD LIFT" is repeating  for some reason that i cannot find.

according to the array "reps" that i have set, it should not be like that.

btw, this tableview is segued from another tableview cell, which is the side menu bar tableview cell in my code.

sorry couldn't upload picture because of reputation

thank you in advance

Comment: I see many "15, 12, 10, 8, 6" in your reps array, did you check you data?

Comment: @jinhualiao the data is correct. if u look at the array and captured image, the displayed label is different

Comment: can you paste the result of your itemsInDays: method?I think that your filteredArray didn't get the right result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indexPath.row is reset when you switch sections causing it to start printing from the beginning of the reps array each time you start a new day.

Comment: how do i solve this problem?, now i see how it is going back to the beginning of the reps array, but how do i fix this?

Comment: try using a counter that is incremented every time you enter the `tableViewcellForRowAtIndexPath`  function to print the right representation of the reps array

Comment: instead of using two separate arrays, would it be more easier if i stored array data in JSON? what I'm thinking is that i can display data with the exercise name and corresponding reps. Or would this be just same with arrays?